# C# Delegates Tutorial Work

Tags: c#, delegates

I've not used delegates before now and I'm trying to figure them out following a tutorial in my book.

So far I've picked up the that a delegate can be used with methods of a class that return the same type object and are overloaded with the same objects as the delegate making the call (please correct me if I'm wrong).

In the tutorial I'm working on, the following code is added to a Car Class:

```
public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string msgForCaller);

private CarEngineHandler listOfHandlers;

public void RegisterWithCarEngine(CarEngineHandler methodToCall)
{
   listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
}
```

In `Main` of the console app the following code is called:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Car c1 = new Car("Slugbug", 100, 10);

    c1.RegisterWithCarEngine(new Car.CarEngineHandler(OnCarEngineEvent));

    Console.WriteLine("**** Speeding Up ******");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        c1.Accelerate(20);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void OnCarEngineEvent(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n***** Message From Car Object *****");
    Console.WriteLine("=> {0}", msg);
    Console.WriteLine("*************************************\n");
}
```

And here is the `Accelerate` method:

```
public void Accelerate(int delta)
{
    if (carIsDead)
    {
        if (listOfHandlers != null)
            listOfHandlers("Sorry, this car is dead...");
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentSpeed += delta;

        if (10 == (MaxSpeed - CurrentSpeed) && listOfHandlers != null)
        {
            listOfHandlers("Careful buddy! Gunna Blow!");
        }
    }

    if (CurrentSpeed >= MaxSpeed)
        carIsDead = true;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("CurrentSpeed = {0}", CurrentSpeed);
}
```

I'm puzzled as to how exactly `listofHandlers` is actually working here? I know this isn't a fault with any code, but I'd like understand more about how delegates actually work? Checking that `listofHandlers` is `null` is throwing me off...

Comment: it's like a variable, except for methods.

Comment: Why check for null though? if your going to pass a string?

Comment: don't you think it might break if you end up passing a string to `null` instead of say... `OnCarEngineEvent`

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm getting myself mixed up, as I was thinking when it passes the string object it was giving the object a value and thats not the case, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Derek - Because the event could be unsubscribed and the event could be triggered at the sametime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Defining a delegate

In C# you can make a pointer to a method. Such a pointer is called a `Delegate`. A delegate *is just a normal object with methods*. It can only point to methods that have matching parameter types and a matching return type.

```
delegate string MyHandler(int value1, string value2);
```

> Defines a delegate type that can point to a method that has (`int`, `string`) as the parameter types and returns a `string`.

You can store such a delegate (pointer to a method) in a field.

```
MyHandler myhandler;
```

This delegate is just an object, so like any object it can be `null`.

#### Creating a new delegate

Given a method:

```
string X(int v1, string v2) { /* ... */ }
```

You can create a new delegate that points to that method:

```
myHandler = new MyHandler(X);
```

Or, thanks to syntactic sugar, you can use this shorter syntax:

```
myHandler = X;
```

#### Invoking the delegate

At any point later, you can invoke the method pointed to by the delegate.

```
int i = 10;
string s = String.Empty;
string result = myHandler.Invoke(i, s);
```

Or, again thanks to syntactic sugar:

```
int i = 10;
string s = String.Empty;
string result = myHandler(i, s);
```

Of course, `myHandler` can be `null`, so you'll need to check that first or you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. After all, you can't call instance methods on `null`.

```
myHandler = null;
myHandler.Invoke(10, "");
```

So, they check for that:

```
string result;
if (myHandler != null)
    result = myHandler(i, s);
```

Or almost equivalent, in C# 6: (Note that `result` will be `null` when `myHandler` is `null`.)

```
string result = myHandler?.Invoke(i, s);
```

#### Why delegates?

If you want to use the same code to call different methods, you can pass a delegate that points to the method to be called as a parameter or field in an object. This is how events are implemented in .NET, and why LINQ works.

Comment: I cant thank you enough for this explanation, exactly what i was looking for, this is how ppl like me can learn .Net development

Answer (score 0):

The null check is because you may not have a `listofHandlers`, if you don't it will be `null`. Just like calling a method of a class that has a value of `null` is illegal, calling a delegate that is `null` is also disallowed.

A delegate provides a way to abstract away a method call. In Java you use an interface that defines a single method, C# just lets you use a delegate directly.

Answer (score 0):

`listOfHandlers` is like a reference variable, except for methods.

Now you don't want to call whatever method `listOfHandlers` contains if it doesn't even contain a method, so you check to make sure that it's not `null` first.

a `null` delegate is a delegate that doesn't have a method defined for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are a reference type in .Net and like all other reference types are initialized with a value of `null` to start.  The `null` check is simply seeing if it's been initialized to a value yet.  If there are no listeners then there is nothing to report by invoking the delegate

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now, by declaring :- private CarEngineHandler listOfHandlers; im declaring a null object, as it hasnt yet been initialised, at what point does it get initialsed? what is the "Listener"?

Comment: @Derek it is initialized in the `RegisterWithCarEngine` method. The listener is the object to which the delegate is bound (if it's not static).  essentially the method which runs when the delegate is invoked