# Understanding Delegates and Delegate Syntax

Tags: c#, delegates

I have this line of code, it works but I don't understand it:

```
Genres.Find(delegate (Genre genre) { return genre.Id == id; });
```

Genres is a list of genre(music)

What exactly is happening here?

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: How does it work sry!

Comment: do you know lamda expressions..?

Comment: Only problem when i google it i get a lot of stackoverflow answers, but unfortunateli none of them answers mt question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228785/c-sharp-delegates-tutorial-work ?

Comment: Side note: explaining what you already understand will help one to provide answer that explains what you are interested in, not random pieces that you may or may not already know.

Comment: It is an anonymous method, training wheels for lambda expressions.  Which is probably what you should use today, easier to recognize.

Comment: @Alexei: I think it is obvious what the question is here. He does not get the idea of delegates here.

Comment: @Matthias based on answers I don't think it is such a clear cut... Especially looking at answer accepted by OP.

Comment: The best reference for delegates is C# in depth by Jon Skeet .it can be really helpful.but you should know a little about delagets before start reading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says, find the Genre (from the list `Genres`) which has the Id equal to the value from the variable `id`.

The keyword `delegate` says, that this is a kind of inline function which decides whether the check is true for each item or not. The beginning `(Genre genre)` says "given I would call each element `genre` in the loop, I can check each items' Id with its named variable `Id`". This is: `genre.Id == id`.

A modern approach would be the usage of lambdas like:

```
var x = Genres.Find(g => g.Id == id);
```

In this case `g` is your loop variable you can check against.

Answer (score 3):

C# provides two ways of defining delegates without writing a named method for it - the old [*anonymous method*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) syntax introduced in C# 2.0, and the shorter lambda syntax introduced in C# 3.0.

Your code is the old way of writing this:

```
Genres.Find(genre => genre.Id == id);
```

This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx) describes the evolution of anonymous functions in C#.

Your `Find` method takes a *predicate* delegate. Depending on the version of .NET targeted by your code it may or may not be the [`System.Predicate<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate, but its functionality is equivalent. An anonymous method in parentheses provides an implementation of your predicate, allowing you to pass arbitrary conditions to your `Find(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive way to see it:

```
Genres.Find(   --- The CompareGenres function is being called from here ---    );

 bool CompareGenres(Genre genre)
 {
   return genre.Id == id; 
 }
```

Find accepts a Predicate < T >, T is the type of the parameter, in this case: you're passing an instance of Genre which is being supplied by the Find method.

"The Predicate is a delegate to a method that returns true if the object passed to it matches the conditions defined in the delegate."

So you're just passing a method as a parameter in the form of a delegate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not use the right terms here. But form an abstract point of view: The Find method here accepts a delegate as parameter. It allows you to implement the "find" algorithm (here comparing the id). It is flexible code you could also compare any other object of "genre".